# How to upload a New Version of an existing File using lightning:fileUpload lightning base component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, fileupload

Does anyone have an idea about uploading a new version of a File in Lightning Component using the base lightning component `lightning:fileUpload`?

I tried passing `ContentDocumentId` into `recordId` parameter, but it returns error on upload.

```
<lightning:fileUpload  name="fileUploader"
                           label= "Demo Upload"
                           multiple="true"
                           recordId="{!v.recordId}" />
```

Comment: please share your component code including apex controller if applicable, thanks

Comment: component code was just one line, I've added to my question now.

Comment: What about your apex controller, this component won’t update/replace existing files on its own

Comment: I didn't had any APEX Controller. The only hook I see in docs is `onuploadfinished`, that happens after we upload document. What else can we do in APEX regarding this component?

Comment: You want to replace/update the existing attached document? So you would manage that part of the logic in your apex controller

Comment: Oh so you mean, if I've 2 Content records, I can make 1 record a version of another in APEX. I didn't knew we can do that. Can you guide me further with some code pointers?

Comment: @VarunC Did you find an answer for this question? I'm having the same issue today.

Comment: No, but the answer suggested by @Itai is a good workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done with the `lightning:fileUpload` component.

I solved this problem with the [lightning:openFiles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_openFiles.htm) event.

This way a user has a preview of the file and inside the previewer you can upload a new version, delete, download and so on:

[image]

Here is some code sample:

**Markup**

```
<aura:attribute name="file" type="ContentDocumentLink" description="content file - taken from server" />

<div onclick="{!c.previewFile}" id="{!file.ContentDocumentId}">
    <lightning:tile label="{!file.fileName}" title="Click to preview and manage uploaded file">
        <aura:set attribute="media">
            <lightning:icon iconName="doctype:unknown" size="xx-small"/>
        </aura:set>
    </lightning:tile>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
previewFile: function(component, event, helper) {
    var contentId = event.currentTarget.id;
    $A.get('e.lightning:openFiles').fire({
        recordIds: [contentId]
    });
},
```