# Uploading Content as a new version via LWC File Upload

Tags: contentversion, fileupload

I am trying to provide a custom interface for uploading a new version of a file in Experience Cloud. I know folks have asked this [before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215030/how-to-upload-a-new-version-of-an-existing-file-using-lightningfileupload-light), but with the ability to add a custom field to file upload, I was hoping this was now possible, but so far no luck.

Background - in Anon Debug, I can set the ContentDocumentId on insert of ContentVersion, and it updates that ContentDocument record instead of creating a new one:

```
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.Title = 'Test New Version Two';
cv.ContentDocumentId = '069Ho00000PRfQsIAL';
cv.VersionData = blob.valueof('Test New Version Body 2');
cv.PathonClient = 'testnewversion.txt';
insert cv;
```

And this also works:

```
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.Title = 'Test New Version Three';
cv.Content_Document_Id_from_Flow_fileupload__c = '069Ho00000PRfQsIAL';
cv.VersionData = blob.valueof('Test New Version Body 33');
cv.PathonClient = 'testnewversion3.txt';
insert cv;
```

But any attempt to do this via a LWC File Upload just gives a vague error of 'Can't upload xx'. The approach I am trying is to add a custom field to File Upload, and set it in the beforeinsert trigger. I can see it being set in the trigger, so maybe this is a timing or permissions issue, but is this approach below just not possible, or am I going about it wrong? Note - it does work if I don't specify a ContentDocumentId, but obviously then just creates a new Document.

//LWC

```
<template>

    <lightning-input value={currentDocId} label="Content Id" onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
        <lightning-file-upload
                label="Upload New Version"
                name="fileUploader"
                multiple="false"
                file-field-name="Content_Document_Id_from_Flow_fileupload__c"
                file-field-value={currentDocId}
                onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
        >
        </lightning-file-upload>
</template>
```

//Controller

```
import {api, LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class CustomFileUpload extends LightningElement {
    currentDocId;
    handleUploadFinished(event) {
        const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
        console.log('No. of files uploaded : ' + uploadedFiles.length);
    }
    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.currentDocId = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

//Trigger on ContentVersion

```
trigger ContentVersionTest on ContentVersion (before insert) {

    for (ContentVersion cvloop: Trigger.New) {
        if (String.isNotBlank(cvloop.Content_Document_Id_from_Flow_fileupload__c) ) {
            cvloop.ContentDocumentId = cvloop.Content_Document_Id_from_Flow_fileupload__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Exec Anon should also fail if you use `cv.Content_Document_Id_from_Flow_fileupload__c = '069Ho00000PRfQsIAL';` instead of `cv.ContentDocumentId = '069Ho00000PRfQsIAL';` I don't think there's a way to update a document with a new version this way. You'll need to come up with an alternative workaround, such as using the `createRecord` method with a `lightning-input type="file"`.

Comment: No - that actually seems to work fine in Exec Anon as well.
lightning-input type="file" does also work, but the file size limits mean it it is not really practical in this use case

Comment: I may have worked it out - when I compared my apex to file upload, I noticed FirstPublishLocationId was being set by the LWC version. When I blanked that out if I passed in a custom ContentDocumentId, it seems to work - need to validate though

Comment: I think that tracks. Probably something in the file uploader that assumes FirstPublishLocationId means you want to create a new document rather than update an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

I used the information in this post to upload a new content version to an existing content document using the standard lightning-file-upload component, with the added requirement that the owner of the ContentDocument had to remain the same.

Thank you for your help!

Don't forget that your custom field must end in `fileupload__c`.

Before insert trigger handler:

```
private static void mapNewVersionFields(List<ContentVersion> newListCV) {
            Set<Id> contentDocumentIdSet = new Set<Id>();
            for (ContentVersion cvloop: newListCV) {
                if (String.isNotBlank(cvloop.Original_ContentDocumentId_fileupload__c) ) {
                    contentDocumentIdSet.add(cvloop.Original_ContentDocumentId_fileupload__c);
                }
            }
            Map<Id,ContentDocument> cdMap = new Map<Id,ContentDocument>([SELECT OwnerId FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id IN: contentDocumentIdSet]);
            for (ContentVersion cvloop: newListCV) {
                if (String.isNotBlank(cvloop.Original_ContentDocumentId_fileupload__c) ) {
                    cvloop.OwnerId = cdMap.get(cvloop.Original_ContentDocumentId_fileupload__c).OwnerId;
                    cvloop.ContentDocumentId = cvloop.Original_ContentDocumentId_fileupload__c;
                    cvloop.FirstPublishLocationId = null;
                    cvloop.Original_ContentDocumentId_fileupload__c = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

HTML:

```
<lightning-file-upload
    label=""
    name="newFileUpload"
    file-field-name="Original_ContentDocumentId_fileupload__c"
    file-field-value={contentDocumentId}
    accept={acceptedFileTypes}
    record-id={recordId}
    onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
  >
  </lightning-file-upload>
```